# Not able to read streaming data from Kafka using pyspark in google colab

Tags: pyspark, apache-kafka, google-colaboratory, spark-structured-streaming

I am running pyspark on google colab. I have set up Kafka and added a csv file in a topic. If I don't use structured streaming to read from kafka, I am able to read the data and print it.

[image]

However, when I try to read the same data using spark structured streaming, the loop just keeps on running without anything getting printed on the terminal.

[image]

How, do I print the data in this case ? Any help will be much appreciated. Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Printing to a console doesn't work nicely in environments like Colab or Databricks. What you can do instead is to use `memory` sink:

```
query = streaming_df.writeStream.format("memory").queryName("streaming_df").start()
```

Then, you can query your in-memory output using:

```
spark.sql("SELECT * FROM streaming_df").show()
```